# Have a Pesky Centering Issue With Button

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to center the "view" buttons on my Writings and Projects page, on portrait-oriented mobile devices. However, I can't quite get this to work. Sub-optimally, I've been using translateX as a bandaid solution; however, this doesn't get the job done on multiple screen widths. Here is my current code:

```
<div class="image-button-wrapper">
   <div class="image-button sqs-dynamic-text">
      <div class="image-button-inner">
         <a href="...">View</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) { 
   .image-button-wrapper { 
      max-width: 150px; 
         transform: translateX(56%); 
         }}
```

So far, none of the centering tricks I can think of have proven effective: `margin: 0 auto;`, `text-align: center;`, etc. Does anybody have a clue how to fix what should be a simple issue?

Thanks in advance!

Tyler

Comment: I'd recommend adding your full HTML/CSS here as a code snippet, because as they say, a code snippet is worth a thousand words.

Comment: not much to go on here. Can you provde the closing tags for the html and more css.

Comment: @Dejan.S Added closing tags. Can you both clarify what else may be helpful? I have no written CSS for the button, beyond what the template may ship with. I could hunt that down.

Comment: What do you need the media query for? It works perfectly fine without. `.image-button-wrapper {text-align: center}` by itself does the trick. So if you could provide the context for why the media query is needed, that would be nice.

Comment: @Mister Lister I need the query because I only desire horizontal centering at that screen size. When flipping to landscape, or on tablet/desktop screens, the default placement works as the layout isn't relegated to a stack.

Comment: But like I said, the code you tried works fine. Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sscq92h1/). Doesn't it match your requirements? If not, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @MrLister Unfortunately it does not; the button is offset to the left, in relation to center. I actually think it didn't work unless I used `!important`, but that bumped the button up close to the caption. Fixable, but not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue isn't that it's difficult to do, but in that there so many different ways of doing it, depending on the situation, it's hard to know which to reach for.

---

For example for horizontal unknown width:

use this :

---

```css
.image-button-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative
}
.image-button-inner {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-button-wrapper">
   <div class="image-button sqs-dynamic-text">
      <div class="image-button-inner">
         <a href="...">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For Vertical use this :

---

```css
.image-button-wrapper ,.image-button.sqs-dynamic-text{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative
}
.image-button-inner {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display:table;
  vertical-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-button-wrapper">
   <div class="image-button sqs-dynamic-text">
      <div class="image-button-inner">
         <a href="...">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for both use :

---

```css
.image-button-wrapper ,.image-button.sqs-dynamic-text{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative
}

.image-button-inner {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-button-wrapper">
   <div class="image-button sqs-dynamic-text">
      <div class="image-button-inner">
         <a href="...">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To know more this is why `transform:translate(-50%)` is used :

---

[image]